# I cannot get my program output to align correctly in Java

Tags: java

These are the instructions...
Write a class that will calculate a planet's measurements.

1. Write a class with these methods.

   - A constructor that initializes the planet's circumference in miles or
     kilometers
   - Methods to calculate the planet's measurements
     - Circle, Area, Diameter, Radius, Surface, Area, Volume
2. Write a program using your class that
   - Asks the user for a planet's circumference
   - Creates a planet object
   - Prints the planet's measurements with commas and decimals
   - Make sure the decimals line up.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main planet = new Main();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        classP cP = new classP();


        //cP.getRadius();
        //cP.getCirleArea();
        //cP.getcirc();

    }
}
```

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class classP {
    private double circ, radius, circleArea, surfArea, volume;
    //public classP radius;
    //public double circ;
    //public double circleArea;

    public Main planet = new Main();

    public classP() {
        this.circ = circ;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.circleArea = circleArea;
        this.surfArea = surfArea;
        this.volume = volume;

        Main mainClass = new Main();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");

        System.out.print("What is the planet's circumference in miles?  ");
        double circ = in.nextDouble();
        double radius = circ / (Math.PI * 2);
        double circleArea = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        System.out.printf("%nThe radius of the planet is: " + "%,12.1f\n" , radius);
        System.out.printf("%nThe area of the planet is: " + "%,12.1f\n", circleArea);
        double diameter = circ / Math.PI;
        System.out.printf("%nThe diameter of the planet is: " + "%,12.1f\n", diameter);
        double surfArea = 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        System.out.printf("%nThe surface area of the planet is: " + "%,12.1f\n", surfArea);
        double volume = (4.0 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
        System.out.printf("%nThe volume of the planet is: " + "%,12.1f\n", volume);
    }


    //public final double getcirc(){
    //    return this.circ;
    //}
    //public final classP getRadius(){
    //    return this.radius;
    //}
    //public final double getCirleArea() {
    //    return this.circleArea;
    //}
}
```

This is my output with a sample user input of: 100

```
What is the planet's circumference in miles?  100

The radius of the planet is:         15.9

The radius of the planet is: 15.9        

The area of the planet is:        795.8

The area of the planet is: 795.8       

The diameter of the planet is: 31.8                          

The surface area of the planet is: 3,183.1                       

The volume of the planet is: 16,886.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some basic improvement of your code. There are so many unnecessary codes that exist in the code blocks. I try to organize them. It  may guide you.

For similar printing, create a custom template with a printer function using `String.format`. It is very easy to maintain actually.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main planet = new Main();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("What is the planet's circumference in miles?  ");
        double circ = in.nextDouble();
        
        ClassP cP = new ClassP(circ);
        cP.calculateData();
        cP.print();

    }

}

class ClassP{
    
    private double circ, radius, circleArea, diameter, surfArea, volume;

    public ClassP(double circ) {
        this.circ = circ;  
    }
    
    public void calculateData() {
        radius = circ / (Math.PI * 2);
        circleArea = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        diameter = circ / Math.PI;
        surfArea = 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        volume = (4.0 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
        
    }
    
    public void print() {
        customAlignPrinter("The radius of the planet is:", radius);
        customAlignPrinter("The area of the planet is:", circleArea);
        customAlignPrinter("The diameter of the planet is:",diameter);
        customAlignPrinter("The surface area of the planet is:", surfArea);
        customAlignPrinter("The volume of the planet is:", volume);
    }
    
    public void customAlignPrinter(String msg,double val) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%40s %,20f", msg, val));
    }
    
}
```

Output Console:

```
What is the planet's circumference in miles?  100
            The radius of the planet is:            15.915494
              The area of the planet is:           795.774715
          The diameter of the planet is:            31.830989
      The surface area of the planet is:         3,183.098862
            The volume of the planet is:        16,886.863940
```

Comment: This is very helpful as well. I am still very new so I am learning. I am slowly getting better. I also worked a bit and found out instead of ("%40s") I could put ("%-40s") and it would align the strings to the left. You both helped me out tremendously and I am grateful. This was my first question posted on here and it is awesome.

Comment: Yes, this place is very good for learning. We help each other for learning and improve ourselves. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a format string that you can pass the labels to that specifies a padded space big enough for the longest one.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class classP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the planet's circumference in miles?  ");

        double circ = in.nextDouble();
        double radius = circ / (Math.PI * 2);
        double circleArea = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);

        System.out.println();

        String format = "%35s %,12.1f\n";

        System.out.printf(format, "The radius of the planet is" , radius);
        System.out.printf(format, "The area of the planet is", circleArea);
        double diameter = circ / Math.PI;
        System.out.printf(format, "The diameter of the planet is", diameter);
        double surfArea = 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        System.out.printf(format, "The surface area of the planet is", surfArea);
        double volume = (4.0 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
        System.out.printf(format, "The volume of the planet is", volume);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
What is the planet's circumference in miles?  100

        The radius of the planet is         15.9
          The area of the planet is        795.8
      The diameter of the planet is         31.8
  The surface area of the planet is      3,183.1
        The volume of the planet is     16,886.9
```

Comment: CryptoFool! That's just what I needed. Thank you very much. I had been working on it afterwards and from what you put it looks like I was on the right path.

Comment: Yeah.  You were getting there!